# Merging large datasets

Tags: r, tidyverse

Im trying to categorize one dataframe based on information in another dataframe. In df1 I have information on the measurement type (e.g. if a jar contained wet or dry soil and whether or not the treatment was "None" or "ul5") at a given time. In df2 I have information on what a measured value X was at a given time. I need to know the measurement type for every measured value of X.

@Ronak Shah came up with this great solution below, however since the datasets are large I get this Error: cannot allocate vector of size 56.2 Gb

```
library(dplyr)

tidyr::crossing(df1 %>%rename(Timestamp1 = Timestamp), 
                df2 %>% rename(Timestamp2 = Timestamp)) %>%
  mutate(diff = as.numeric(Timestamp2 - Timestamp1)) %>%
  filter(diff > 0) %>% 
  arrange(Jar, Timestamp2, diff) %>%
  group_by(Timestamp2) %>%
  slice(1L) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  arrange(Timestamp2) %>%
  select(-diff)
```

Any ideas as how to merge the large dataset? I have an ThinkPad intel Corei7 8th Gen, so my computer is not super slow.

Here's df1:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Jar = c("Soil_dry", "Soil_dry", "soil_wet", "soil_wet", 
"Soil_dry", "Soil_dry", "soil_wet"), Treatment = c("None", "None", 
"None", "None", "ul5", "ul5", "ul5"), Timestamp = structure(c(1608129063, 
1608129122, 1608129126, 1608129136, 1608129189, 1608129242, 1608129252
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(Jar = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Treatment = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Timestamp = structure(list(format = ""), class = c("collector_datetime", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

df2:

```
df2 <- structure(list(X = c(5, 3, 34, 4, 65, 9, 7), Timestamp = structure(c(1608129064, 
1608129122, 1608129125, 1608129133, 1608129188, 1608129240, 1608129243
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(X = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Timestamp = structure(list(format = ""), class = c("collector_datetime", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

Desired data:

```
desired_data <- structure(list(X = c(5, 3, 34, 4, 65, 9, 7), Timestamp = structure(c(1608129064, 
1608129122, 1608129125, 1608129133, 1608129188, 1608129240, 1608129243
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Jar = c("Soil_dry", 
"Soil_dry", "Soil_dry", "soil_wet", "soil_wet", "Soil_dry", "Soil_dry"
), Treatment = c("None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "ul5", 
"ul5")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -7L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
    X = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector"
    )), Timestamp = structure(list(format = ""), class = c("collector_datetime", 
    "collector")), Jar = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Treatment = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: Can you include details about number of rows and columns in your actual `df1` and `df2`.

Comment: df1= 225000 obs. 50 variables and df2=67000 obs. , 410 variables

Comment: The memory problems are essentially a consequence of the width of your data. In other words, you are encountering problems you don't need because you carry all 460 variables around, rather than just the half dozen you need to perform the core operation. Create an index for each data `df1$id1 <- seq_len(nrow(df1))` then use `select` on only the columns use above. Then use columns as required.

Comment: @Hugh, I have tried that already and that has not resolved the problem...

Comment: 225k and 67k rows is not "large"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `fuzzyjoin` which might simplify the process.

```
library(dplyr)

fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join(df1, df2, by = 'Timestamp', match_fun = `<`) %>%
  arrange(Jar, Treatment, Timestamp.y) %>%
  group_by(Jar, Treatment, Timestamp.x) %>%
  slice(1L)
```